# How to allow a new owner to reset a used Mac I sold to them? Or can I reset it remotely?

Tags: macos, reset

I was stupid. I bought a new Mac, the old one was sitting on a shelf, and I had a false memory that I reset it to be sold. Then it sold, and I rushed to send it to the buyer (turned out – in a different country). But I forgot to reset it to an as-new state.

I understand there might be protection for those which are stolen to be not usable. This is not the case. So my question is – how to let a buyer reset it without compromising my password? (I'd prefer him to format the SSD and have no access to whatever I might forget to erase.)

Sending the computer back to the States, or giving him a password are the options I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)

Comment: If it’s still part of your iCloud account, you can simply wipe it from your side by launching the “Find My” app, selecting the old machine and then clicking “Erase This Device.” Just coordinate with the new owner to make sure it is turned on and there is network connectivity.